Flutter: Implementing Branch.io (deferred) deep links for referrals and Firebase Auth email links without conflicts
I'm building a referral system in a Flutter app that needs to handle two types of deep links:

Referral links using Branch.io: These need to survive app installation and allow existing users to share links with friends. When a new user installs the app through a referral link, I need to access the referral parameters to reward the referrer.

Authentication links using Firebase Auth: My app already uses App/Universal Links (without plugins) for Firebase email verification and password reset functionality.


With Firebase Dynamic Links being deprecated, I chose Branch.io as an alternative for the referral system. However, I'm facing challenges in making both systems work together without conflicts. When I try to configure Firebase Auth action code settings to work with Branch.io, it requires Firebase Dynamic Links activation, which I'm trying to avoid due to its deprecation.
Questions

Is it possible to use Branch.io exclusively for referral links while keeping Firebase Auth email links working with standard deep linking?
If not, what's the recommended approach to handle both authentication and referral deep links in a Flutter app given Firebase Dynamic Links deprecation?

Expected Behavior:
Referral links should work after app installation with accessible parameters
Authentication links should continue opening directly in-app
Both systems should function independently
Actual Result:
Firebase Auth configuration requires Dynamic Links activation when trying to work with Branch.io
Cannot maintain separate deep link handling for authentication and referrals
user_notifier.dart
Future<void> sendVerificationEmail(User? user) async {
    final response = await FlutterBranchSdk.getShortUrl(
      buo: BranchUniversalObject(
        canonicalIdentifier: 'verifyEmail',
        canonicalUrl: 'https://project-id.web.app/__/auth/action',
        title: "Email verification",
        imageUrl: 'https://example.com/logo.jpg',
        contentDescription: "Email verification for ...",
        keywords: ['Email Verification'],
        contentMetadata: BranchContentMetaData()
          ..addCustomMetadata('email', user?.email)
          ..addCustomMetadata('action', 'auth')
          ..addCustomMetadata('mode', 'verifyEmail'),
      ),
      linkProperties: BranchLinkProperties(
        channel: 'email',
        feature: 'email_verification',
        stage: 'new user',
      ),
    );
    log(response.result);
    return await user
        ?.sendEmailVerification(_getBranchActionCodeSettings(response.result));
  }

  

ActionCodeSettings _getBranchActionCodeSettings(String deepLink) {
    return ActionCodeSettings(
      url: deepLink,
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      androidPackageName: '',
      androidInstallApp: true,
      iOSBundleId: '',
    );
  }

AndroidManifest.xml (Previously, replaced with Branch.io config)
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
  <data android:scheme="http" />
  <data android:host="project-id.web.app"/>
  <data android:host="project-id.firebaseapp.com"/>
  <data android:pathPrefix="/__/auth/action"/>
</intent-filter>

MyApp.dart
FlutterBranchSdk.listSession().listen((data) {
      log(data.toString());

    }, onError: (error) {
      print('listSession error: ${error.toString()}');
    });

After configuring Dynamic Links, I got this data from Branch:
{
    +non_branch_link: https://project-id.web.app/__/auth/action?apiKey=fake-api-key&mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=code&continueUrl=https://branchiodeeplink.test-app.link/AbC123&lang=en,
    +clicked_branch_link: false,
    +is_first_session: false
}

